# Python sort a string in CSV

Tags: python, csv

I want to sort the every row of the CSV string with the following code

```
import csv

def sort_csv_columns(csv_string: str) -> str:
    # Split the CSV string into lines
    lines = csv_string.strip().split("\n")

    # Split the first line (column names) and sort it case-insensitively
    header = lines[0].split(",")
    header.sort(key=str.lower)

    # Split the remaining lines (data rows) and sort them by the sorted header
    data = [line.split(",") for line in lines[1:]]
    data.sort(key=lambda row: [row[header.index(col)] for col in header])

    # Join the sorted data and header into a single CSV string
    sorted_csv = "\n".join([",".join(header)] + [",".join(row) for row in data])
    return sorted_csv

# Test the function
csv_string = "Beth,Charles,Danielle,Adam,Eric\n17945,10091,10088,3907,10132\n2,12,13,48,11"
sorted_csv = sort_csv_columns(csv_string)
print(sorted_csv)
```

Output

```
Adam,Beth,Charles,Danielle,Eric
17945,10091,10088,3907,10132
2,12,13,48,11
```

Expected Output

```
Adam,Beth,Charles,Danielle,Eric\n
3907,17945,10091,10088,10132\n
48,2,12,13,11
```

What am I doing wrong

I am not able to sort the row besides the top header

Comment: You need so.ething to track and map the original column order to the new column order.

Comment: You're sorting the rows, not the columns in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As `data` represents your lines, then `data.sort` can only sort the lines between, them, not the lines content (the cells), you need to sort on each element of `data`
- Also doing the following will always give `0,1,2,3,4` as you check index on the list on iterate on

  ```
  [header.index(col) for col in header]
  ```

---

#### Sort header then reorder

You need sorting, but without `sort` method, you just need to reorder the values regarding the new header order

```
def sort_csv_columns(csv_string: str) -> str:
    lines = csv_string.strip().split("\n")

    initial_header = lines[0].split(",")
    header = sorted(initial_header, key=str.lower)

    data = [line.split(",") for line in lines[1:]]
    data = [[row[initial_header.index(col)] for col in header]
            for row in data]

    sorted_csv = "\n".join([",".join(header)] + [",".join(row) for row in data])
    return sorted_csv
```

---

#### Sort by header but maintain row together

You can avoid the reorder part if you sort the data while having a the content stored by column instead of rows

```
def sort_csv_columns(csv_string: str) -> str:
    data = [line.split(",") for line in csv_string.strip().split("\n")]
    # [['Beth', 'Charles', 'Danielle', 'Adam', 'Eric'], ['17945', '10091', '10088', '3907', '10132']
    # , ['2', '12', '13', '48', '11']]
    data = list(zip(*data))
    # [('Beth', '17945', '2'), ('Charles', '10091', '12'), ('Danielle', '10088', '13'),
    #  ('Adam', '3907', '48'), ('Eric', '10132', '11')]
    
    # sort by first value : name
    data.sort(key=lambda row: row[0].lower())
    sorted_csv = "\n".join([",".join(row) for row in zip(*data)])
    return sorted_csv
```